# ggplot2 passing vectors into scale_alpha_manual() and scale_size_manual() is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to customize colors, size, and alpha of a ggplot with lines using data from a data frame. Specifically I want to highlight an average line superimposed over the other lines. I can get the colors to work, but neither alpha nor size parameters. The structure and code are below.

Appreciate any advice!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- structure(list(V20 = c(0.021331, 0.034844, 0.023003, -0.001772, 
-0.028383, -0.016064, 0, 0.016824, 0.045668, 0.029395), V21 = c(0.088426, 
0.096454, 0.064565, 0.03234, 0.03058, 0.00994800000000001, 0, 
0, 0, 0), V22 = c(0.091629, 0.061091, 0.039268, 0.00933999999999996, 
0.005019, 0.000396000000000007, 0.009496, -0.013611, -0.020616, 
-0.010839), avg = c(0.0130733014285714, -0.00393914761904762, 
-0.00299403809523809, 0.00435276190476191, 0.00829649999999999, 
0.00264482857142857, -0.0120784133333333, -0.00930774761904762, 
0.00377989047619047, 0.00355469323809524), time = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

colors.df <- data.frame(key=c(as.character(colnames(df)[1:length(colnames(df))-1])), 
                        value=rep("gray",length(colnames(df))-1), 
                        alpha=rep(0.2,length(colnames(df))-1),
                        size=rep(1.0,length(colnames(df))-1),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colors.df[which(colors.df$key=='avg'),]$value <- "red"
colors.df[which(colors.df$key=='avg'),]$alpha <- 1.0
colors.df[which(colors.df$key=='avg'),]$size  <- 3.0

df.melt <- melt(df, id='time', variable.name = "spike", value.name = "voltage")

ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=time, y=voltage, colour=spike)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$alpha) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$value) +
  scale_size_manual(values= colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$size)
```

Comment: You can get color work because you're using `colour=spike`, but if you want `alpha` or `size` work you also have to specify them in `aes()`

Comment: so easy! thank you

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @PoGibas for the hint!

```
  ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=time, y=voltage, colour=spike, alpha=spike, size=spike))+ 
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$alpha) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$value) +
  scale_size_manual(values= colors.df[1:length(colors.df$value),]$size)
```